# IDE for Clojure - Counterclockwise(Eclipse) vs Emacs. What (if any) features Counterclockwise is missing comparing to Emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure, counterclockwise

I want to know what are limitations of Counterclockwise plugin for Eclipse comparing to Emacs. What Lisp (and Clojure) magic will not be available from Eclipse?

-- UPDATE --
I know Emacs will have more features, shourtcuts, various sophisticated key bindings, but I am interested in specific Lisp/Clojure stuff. For example if I couldn't use regexp search in files, it's fine, but if I couldn't use REPL inside Eclipse, it would be deal breaker for me - it's core feature. So to expand my question, is REPL fully functional in Counterclockwise comparing to Emacs? I don't mind, if some very advanced features are missing, that are just there for convenience, but if I can't do something, I will just jump to Emacs.

Comment: Very subjective question - So go for Emacs :)

Comment: It'd be much easier to answer if you list the features you need. Otherwise, I'd vote to close the question as nonconstructive and encouraging flame wars (when someone says it's not available in one yet it does exist but happens to require different approach).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counterclockwise has everything you need for a decent Clojure development experience.

The things I find most useful (can't live without!)

- Fully functional REPL
- Paredit mode / automatic paren balencing
- Matched rainbow parens in both REPL and editor
- Syntax highlighting in both REPL and editor
- Integration with Eclipse / Maven for dependency management
- Many keyboard shortcuts (see: https://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/wiki/EditorKeyBindingsFeatures)
- Perfect for Polyglot projects that mix Java + Clojure

I'm pretty happy overall using Counterclockwise as my primary development environment. Not saying it's better than Emacs, but it certainly isn't lacking anything that is a deal-breaker.

Comment: This was the answer I was waiting for. Thank you.

Comment: Not to mention, that if you are learning Clojure, Emacs may just take you over the tipping point of too much.